# Как выполнить скрипт определенное количество раз?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть к примеру подобное:

```
count = 3;
setInterval(function(){

alert(count);

 }, 100);
```

Вот как мне выполнить эту функцию ровно три раза ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Каждый раз уменьшаем `count`, если он равен нулю, то очищаем `setInterval`, через функцию `clearInterval`.

```js
count = 3;
var id = setInterval(function() {
  $.post("/ds.php", {
i: count}, function(data) {});
 //ваша функция
  alert(count--);
 //уменьшаем счетчик
  if (count <= 0) clearInterval(id);
 //если равен нуля, очищаем
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ваш код работает исправно, а вот если добавить в него отправку формы вроде такой:
 count = 3;
var id = setInterval(function() {
    $.post(
  "/ds.php",
  {
    i: count,
  },
  onAjaxSuccess
);

 function onAjaxSuccess(data)
 {   
    
   
 }
 
  alert(count--);
if (count <= 0) clearInterval(id);
}, 100);

то не перестает работать

Comment: @ShevtsovEugene подправил под ваш код

Comment: @Other в чём проблема? Запросы отправляются с нужными `count`, асинхронно, не вижу проблем сделать так.

Comment: спасибо. =) Но кстати нет, не везде один был.

Comment: @ShevtsovEugene Нужно помочь с этим или справитесь?

Comment: Я уже понял в чем проблема была - спасибо=)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let count = 3;

function tmp(){ 
  alert(count);
  
  if(count > 1){
    setTimeout(tmp, 100); // Не используем интервал, ибо равные промежтки получить сложно (см. https://habrahabr.ru/post/138062/)
    count--;
  }
}
tmp();
```

Comment: Вопрос заключался именно в том виде в каком есть, как его выполнить  3 раза, а вы переделали всё. Просто предоставить код недостаточно, добавьте объяснение его.

Comment: @Mr_Epic, вроде не сильно поменялось, зато работает и неплохо, у интервалов плохая заковырка с временем исполнения, я с ними не дружу и другим не советую :) Это ИМХО.